# Oauth2 in Restlet with a JAXRS Application?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jax-rs, restlet

I am trying to create a REST service (in JAX-RS) with Restlet which is protected by OAuth2. Our REST service has already been written with JAX-RS and after some investigation the Oauth2 implementation of Restlet seems to be the best.

Anyone knows how to use OAuth2 from restlet with a jax-rs service (also in restlet if possible)?

I have tried:

```
jaxRsApplication.setAuthenticator(new Authenticator() {
  public boolean authenticate(Request request, Response response) {
    OAuthAuthorizer auth = new OAuthAuthorizer("http://localhost:9090/oauth/validate");
    return auth.authorize(request, response);
  }
});
```

but this doesn't seem to work.